# Basic influxdb cardinality

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I have developed a project using influxdb and I am currently trying to understand why my influx container keeps crashing due to oom exits.

The way I designed my database is quite basic. I have several buildings, for each building, I need to have timebased values. So I created a database for each building, and a measurement for each type of value (for example energy consumption).

I do not use tags at all, because using the design I described above, all I have left to store is the float values and their timestamp index. I like this design because every building is completely separated from the others (as they should be), and if I want to get data from one of them, I just need to connect to the building's database (or bucket) and query it like so :

```
SELECT * FROM field1,field2 WHERE time>d1 and time<d2
```

According to [this influx article](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/data-layout-and-schema-design-best-practices-for-influxdb/), if I understand correctly (english isn't my first langage), I have a cardinality of:

```
3 buildings (bucket/database) * 1000 fields (measurement) * 1 (default tag ?) = 3000 cardinality
```

This doesn't seem to be much, thus I think I misunderstand something.